# CPU overload when updating QListView from QAbstractListModel

Tags: python, python-2.7, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm building a little pyqt5 app that display a list of 512 values in a QListView. The list is updated through separate thread, with QThread.
It's working nice, except the fact that it is using 65/95 % of the CPU of the (old) Core 2 Duo 2,53 Ghz I'm developing on.

I simplify the code to remove dependancies, because the update is done from a network protocol. Updates are done 40 times per second (each 25 ms).

The simplified script below is refreshing the list 10 times per second and the CPU is still at 65 % when list is updated.

Is there anything to do for avoiding the overload?
Is there some best practices to follow for updating a View?

(the global is not in my last code, it's here to have a simple example)

```
from random import randrange
from time import sleep
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QAbstractListModel, Qt, QVariant, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListView, QApplication, QGroupBox, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

universe_1 = [0 for i in range(512)]

class SpecialProcess(QThread):
    universeChanged = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super(SpecialProcess, self).__init__()
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        global universe_1
        universe_1 = ([randrange(0, 101, 2) for i in range(512)])
        self.universeChanged.emit()
        sleep(0.1)
        self.run()


class Universe(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Universe, self).__init__(parent)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(universe_1)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        index = index.row()
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                return universe_1[index]
            except IndexError:
                return QVariant()
        return QVariant()


class Viewer(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__()
        list_view = QListView()
        self.list_view = list_view
        # create a vertical layout
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        universe = Universe()
        vbox.addWidget(list_view)
        # Model and View setup
        self.model = Universe(self)
        self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        # meke a process running in parallel 
        my_process = SpecialProcess()
        my_process.universeChanged.connect(self.model.layoutChanged.emit)
        # set the layout on the groupbox
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(argv)
  group_widget = Viewer()
  group_widget.show()
  exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is that example truly realistic? Does the data *always* change that often? The obvious answer to your question would seem to be: only update when you really need to.

Comment: It's a basic viewer for artnet DMX protocol. Frames are send 40 times per second. I understand that it might be useless to display all values, but how to limit updates? Sorry if it's a quite obvious question, but I don't see any information either on pyqtsignal or qabstractmodel reference pages.

Comment: @ekhumoro  : you think this CPU load is normal when updating a QlistView 10 times per seconds?

Comment: What is the purpose of displaying the values in a list-view, if they are changing so often? Human reaction times are only about a fifth of a second at best, so users aren't going to able to interact with the view in any meaningful fashion. It would seem far simpler to just dump the values as a block of text.

Comment: this protocol is used to control stage-lighting. Values are not supposed to move so often everytime, but it's the protocol speed, that's why I guess it was a good test. The idea behind having a QList is to be able to send values through the QList . This is the next step.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by "send values through the QList".

Comment: I mean selecting a cell with the mouse, and sending a value to the network protocol.

Comment: But, given the points I made earlier, it therefore makes no sense to update the list so often. Can you not see the rather obvious race-condition here? In the time it takes the user to click an item, the value could potentially change several times! To make the interface usable, you should update maybe once every two seconds, and block interaction with the list whilst it is updating.

Comment: You're right, again. Is there a way to limit the updating rate of the view?

Comment: Sure - in the example you can just do `sleep(2)`. Or you could just have a counter and only emit the signal every N steps. Or use a QTimer.

Comment: Ah, of course … Thank you again !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a normal behavior…